# Dynamic class loading vs injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dynamic-class-loaders

The application I'm developing uses third party services for customer verification. As our customers may use different services I've created a common interface and would like the actual implementation to be provided later via configuration parameters.

I'm currently instantiating the class using reflection:

```
Class<? extends Checker> _class = Class.forName(implementorName).asSubclass(Checker.class);
Constructor<? extends Checker> ctor = _class.getDeclaredConstructor(DatabaseSession.class);
cc = ctor.newInstance(db());
```

But I'm reading that dynamic class loading should be avoided in production due to degrading performances.

I'm aware of injection techniques but I don't want to introduce a whole new framework (with all its frills) just for a single case.

Are there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Just because you read something doesn't mean you should take it as gospel. There's a difference between "should be avoided" and "should never be used". Although I'm fairly sure that there's a better way to do what you need than specify classnames like that.

Comment: if you just load it once after starting server, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @柯鴻儀 I was actually thinking to instantiate it only once and store it in a static field but I would have to provide the database session differently

Comment: @algiogia I think for every new session object,it still doesn't matter.the thing is about reloading a specific class dynamically and do it many times at runtime or not.  IMHO

Comment: if you just "class.forName(...)" once , this class is just loaded by a classloader once . after that ,"newInstance(...)" won't reload the class, I think it won't impact the performance too much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just providing a different jar for different customers? The jar would contain that customer's implementation of the common interface + necessary factory methods.

This is a bit like a driver, e.g. a printer driver. You would essentially have a "customer driver" for each customer.

Comment: We already have different jar. Unfortunately they don't implement a common interface so I had to write adapters

Comment: @algiogia Yes, and on top of those adapters you put a common interface. Been there, done that :)

Comment: are you suggesting to write a jar for each adapter?

Comment: @algiogia Possibly, yes. It's a bit hard to tell without more information around your project. But the point is, you would have a set of jars, unique to each customer, that together acts as the "driver", and they would expose an implementation of the common interface to the main program. Then you would replace the whole "jar set" for different customers. The main program doesn't care as long as it can find an implementation of that interface when it runs.